# POST not supported exception after call to REST service using XHR send

Tags: javascript, java, rest, http, spring-boot

I have a REST api developed using Spring Boot which accepts POST requests and does some processing on them. It would then redirect to a different results page. 
The controller is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/person")
    public String arrayTest(@RequestParam("personid") String personid, Model model) throws IOException{
        CoreDriver driver=new CoreDriver();
        ResultData result=driver.initProcess(personid);
        model.addAttribute("attr",result.getMismatchList());
        return "results";

    }
```

In this case, after the initProcess function is complete, it would be redirected to a page: results.html
This works when i invoke the service using a form submit as follows:

```
<form id="mainform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/person">
            <table BORDER="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter person ID</td>
                    <td>
                        <input  type="text" name="personid" id="person">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

However, when I invoke the service using the send function of XHR, it successfully invokes the REST api but it does not redirect to the results.html page. Instead it gives me an error: Request method 'POST' not supported.
My javascript for this is as follows:

```
upload: function(image_data_uri, target_url, callback) {
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("POST", target_url, false);
var form = new FormData();
        var arrayLength = proc_image_data.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++) {

        form.append( form_name, proc_data[j], form_name+"."+fmt.replace(/e/, '') );
}

        http.send(form);
    }
```

This JS function is called using the following form:

```
<form id="mainform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
            <table BORDER="1">

                <tr>
                    <td>Enter person ID</td>
                    <td>
                        <input  type="text" name="personid" id="person">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="submit"  onclick="shot()"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

function shot() {
        var personId=document.getElementById('person').value;
        var url='/person?personid='+personId;
                Test.upload( webcamuri, url, function(code, text) {

        } );
    }
```

I'm not sure why the redirection works when i invoke the api directly from the form but not via the JS that uses XHR send. Could you please help in identifying the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem related to [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) - cross origin resource sharing. To be able to access the REST service via XHR, the service must send the right headers to the browser (which probably is doing a prefligth request).

You can achieve this in your REST controller by adding the `@CrossOrigin` annotation to your `arrayTest`method. (see [Spring docu](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/))

Comment: I am able to access the REST service via XHR, but the problem is that the redirection is not happening as expected. As per your suggestion, I did try adding the @CrossOrigin annotation, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to resolve the issue after a bit of debugging. I removed the `method` attribute from the form as well as added the following code inside the callback function for `Test.upload():`

```
document.write(text);
```

So basically, `text` returns the html of the redirected page. So once the `XHR send` call is complete, the html is written to the browser via the callback.